# Reformat Linux command output

Tags: linux, shell

Running the following command:

```
root@kbl1infn1 # hpasmcli -s "show dimm" | egrep "Module|Status"
```

will produce:

```
Module #:                     1
Status:                       Ok
Module #:                     3
Status:                       Ok
Module #:                     6
Status:                       Ok
Module #:                     8
Status:                       Ok
Module #:                     1
Status:                       Ok
Module #:                     3
Status:                       Ok
Module #:                     6
Status:                       Ok
Module #:                     8
Status:                       Ok
```

How can I reformat the output to become like:

```
Module: 1  3  6  8 ...
Status: OK OK OK OK
```

Comment: hpasmcli, I understand your situation. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using AWK

```
hpasmcli -s "show dimm" | awk '
/^Module/ { m = m sprintf("%4s", $3) }
/^Status/ { s = s sprintf("%4s", $2) }
END       { print "Module:" m "\n" "Status:" s }'
```

Sample output:

```
Module:   1   3   6   8   1   3   6   8
Status:  Ok  Ok  Ok  Ok  Ok  Ok  Ok  Ok
```

---

The blocks in curly braces after regular expressions `/^Module/` and `/^Status/` are executed when the current record (line) matches the corresponding regular expression. The values are collected into `m` and `s` variables. At the `END`, both variables are printed to the standard output.

`sprintf` functions return the strings padded to the specified width (4).

---

Alternatively, split the records with a colon using `-F:` option. But then you will need to trim the values using `gsub` function, for instance:

```
hpasmcli -s "show dimm" | awk -F: '
/^Module/ { gsub(/ +/, "", $2); m = m sprintf("%4s", $2) }
/^Status/ { gsub(/ +/, "", $2); s = s sprintf("%4s", $2) }
END       { print "Module:" m "\n" "Status:" s }'
```

## Using Perl

```
hpasmcli -s "show dimm" | perl -e '
while (<>) {
  push @m, m/:\s*(\S+)$/ if /^Module/;
  push @s, m/:\s*(\S+)$/ if /^Status/;
}
print "Module: ", join("", map { sprintf "%4s", $_ } @m), "\n";
print "Status: ", join("", map { sprintf "%4s", $_ } @s), "\n";'
```

The `while` loop reads the input line by line. If a line starts with "Module", then the value is extracted from the line using `m/:\s*(\S+)$/` expression. The matching group of non-space characters `(\S+)` is added to `@m`, or `@s` arrays. Finally, the array items are joined and printed to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

You can tailor two `grep`s and `cut`s this way, combining with `printf` to format and `echo` to concatenate the values:

```
echo -e "Module: $(printf %5d $(hpasmcli -s "show dimm" | grep Module | cut -f2 -d:))\nStatus: $(printf %5s $(hpasmcli -s "show dimm" |grep Status | cut -f2 -d:))"
```

If you want to make a single call to `hpasmcli`, then:

```
hpasmcli -s "show dimm" > outfile
echo -e "Module: $(printf %5d $(grep Module outfile | cut -f2 -d:))\nStatus: $(printf %5s $(grep Status outfile | cut -f2 -d:))"
```

The output:

```
Module:     1    3    6    8    1    3    6    8
Status:    Ok   Ok   Ok   Ok   Ok   Ok   Ok   Ok
```